# Can an infinite(never ending) algorithm be called a correct algorithm?

Tags: algorithm

An algorithm is informally defined as a well defined sequence of computational procedures.But can we call a sequence of procedures which theoretically never ends a correct algorithm ?
Is it must for a "correct algorithm" to complete in finite time??
Eg: Digital Watches.They work on "set of procedures" which never ends.But still it's an effective set of procedures. So, can we call this as an algorithm.

Comment: Conceptual questions regarding algorithm might be more on place on programmers.stackexchange.com . StackOverflow is more suited for programming questions involving real code. (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in )

Comment: See http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/semi-algorithm . The existence of this definition implies that the answer to your question is “no”

Comment: Voting to close as "too broad", as this answer will most likely cause debates and raise several existing definition, and no one will convince the others one definition is correct and others are not. This is a great question for forums, but unfortunately does not fit the question-answer format well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said on Wikipedia:

> Generally, a program is only an algorithm if it stops eventually.

Wikipedia contributors. Algorithm [Internet]. Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia; 2014 Jul 10, 23:39 UTC [cited 2014 Jul 25]. Available from: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Algorithm&oldid=616454945.